# Android Theming toolbar isn't themed correctly

Tags: android, themes, android-dark-theme

Trying to add Dark Mode to my app.  I am mostly there, most things work as I expect after I made the required changes, however I have a problem with the Toolbar.  What have I missed?

[Screenshot of Toolbar issue, and layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHKO3.png)

Comment: Can you post the whole activity xml that includes this toolbar?

Comment: Also, clarify exactly what you are expecting to happen!

Comment: the rather large white area is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying AppTheme to `popupTheme`, what does it have?

You don't usually need to make a custom one, one of the pre-made ones like `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar` is enough.

And actually, if you're using MaterialComponents, you don't need to apply anything to your app to make it work in Dark Mode, just use the DayNight MaterialComponents theme.